# I want to use the Element at , length and substring method to remove something from string in c#

Tags: c#

Problem statement:

> Using just the `ElementAt`, `Length`, and `Substring` string methods and the `+` (concatenate)
>   operator, write a function that accepts a string s, a start position p, and a length l, and returns s with the characters starting in position p for a length of l removed. Don’t forget that strings start at position 0. Thus (“abcdefghijk”, 2, 4) returns “abghijk”. Don’t use any “remove” or similar built-in string gadget.

I tried to do this

```
static string rstring(string str, int p, int l)
{    
    string end= "";

    for (int i=0 ; i<p; i++){
        end+= str[i];
    }
    for (int i=p+l ; i<str.length i++){
        end+= str[i];
    }

    return end;

}
```

I tried to do this but i couldn't figure out to use ElementAT and substring. Any help will be appricated.

Comment: Any time you can't figure out a method the first thing to do is [read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.elementat?view=netcore-2.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_ElementAt__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Int32_)

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd even need to use `ElementAt`.  It can be accomplished with just the other constraints.  It's just  `return str.Substring(0, p) + str.Substring(p + l);` but with some checks to make sure p and p+l are not beyond the end of the string and that neither is negative (presumably an exception case).

Answer (score 0):

You're using `[]` which is essentially the same thing as `ElementAt`, and if you look at your loops they're basically doing the same thing as `Substring`, albeit less efficiently because you're building up and throwing away a bunch of intermediate strings.

That said, I don't see why you'd use *both* -- you'd just use one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

This basically just accepts a string, a start and an end and then returns a new string according to those parameters.

This is probably the easiest way to explain Substrings. They accept a start and end and then give you back a new string according to your start and end.

```
public string ReturnSubstring(string str, int start, int end)
{
    return str.Substring(start, end);
}

var firstHalf = ReturnSubstring(myString, 0, 3);
var secondHalf = ReturnSubstring(myString, 6, myString.Length);
var newString = firstHalf + secondHalf;
```

Comment: This won't work for the problem, he is trying to remove the middle part of the string.

Comment: Because he doesn't want a substring, he wants characters on both ends of the string. Use your method on his sample case and you will see.

Comment: You're right, updated my answer to clarify how I wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `Substring()` or `Remove()` or any other string maninpulation I would use a simple loop (this doesn't include, but should include error handling).

```
for (int i=0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    if (i  < p || i > l+1) end += str[i];
}
```